# Update a Global list in Dask

Tags: python, dask

I want to read in a stream of float numbers, do some simple calculation and append the value into a global list. Can you tell where I get it wrong? The list is not appending.

```
from random import random
from time import sleep

def process(x):
    from random import random
    sleep(random()*2)
    t = x * 2
    processed_queue.append(t)
    print(processed_queue)
    return t

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from distributed import Client
    from queue import Queue

    client = Client()

    processed_queue = []
    input_q = Queue()

    remote_q = client.scatter(input_q)
    processed_q = client.map(process, remote_q)
    result_q = client.gather(processed_q)

    for i in [random() for x in range(100)]:
        sleep(random())
        input_q.put(i)
        print(i)
        print(processed_queue)
        print(result_q.qsize())
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilest `queue.Queue` and `multiprocessing.Queue` can be used to send data between threads and processes, generally this kind of programming-by-side-effect is not the model encouraged by dask.

You are able to pass data to functions executed by the cluster and get their return values in real time using `client.submit`, what are the queues doing for you that you cannot do otherwise? In addition, there are some dask constructs such as shared variables that maybe could do this, but (again) that is rarely used and I think unlikely the right paradigm for you.

For the specific reason that the code is not working for you: `Client()` creates at least one separate process for the scheduler and one for a worker with one or more threads (see your task-manager, top, or other system-watching tool). The `queue.Queue` is process-local, so each process will see the empty queue and add to it, but that information is not seen in the main process, and actions on the input queue are not seen in the workers.